# How to get column name list from java.sql.ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

```
try{

   connection = dataSource.getConnection();
   callableStatement.setInt(2, clientId);
    ....... // some stuff
   resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();

}
```

Now I have a resultSet , but don't know column names? How do I retrive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
ResultSetMetaData    rsmd    =    resultSet.getMetaData();
int    columnCount    =    rsmd.getColumnCount();
// The column count starts from 1
for    (int    i=1;   i<=columnCount;    i++ ) {
  String name    =    rsmd.getColumnName(i);
  // Do stuff with name
}
```

Comment: Add a small explanation to explain this code.

Answer (score 0):

`resultSet.getMetadata()` returns you a `ResultSetMetaData` object that has the column names (e.g. `resultSet.getMetadata().getColumnName(1)` )

Comment: If you want to know the names of the columns of the result set, then `getColumnLabel` is more correct. `getColumnLabel` returns the alias or the original column name (if there is no alias), while `getColumnName` returns the name of the underlying column (if any).

Answer (score 0):

show this:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ResultSetMetaData

```
 ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();

ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
  String columnName = metadata.getColumnName(i);
  columns.add(columnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code helps to get the column names of the table.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnsCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
int i=1;
while (i <= columnsCount){
    String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    i++;
}
```